# How to remove the last empty space in css flex

Tags: html, flexbox

I am using css flex on my project but it adds an empty box at the end of the items. How do I remove it?

My code

```
<div className="form-horizontal">
  <div className="form-control">
    <label htmlFor="">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  </div>
  <div className="form-control">
     <label htmlFor="">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-horizontal{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show your CSS as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This should solve your problem

```
.form-control {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the `display: flex;` will make your child elements inside them have a display of inline, so they will stick to each other, unless you separate them with `justify-content` or `align-items`.

Now if you have 2 elements (the child's elements) which their combined width is still less than the width of container box (parent element), well the rest of width missing is still there, just that it's not being used! (Because you need to maintain the aspect/design of the page)

But that doesn't means that you have a new box in your **flex-blox**. It's just free space, not being used.

[Graphic explanation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4SaC.png)

Now you can still use that free space there with the `justify-content` or `align items` property, or you can add a new child element to the **flex-blox**!